# Need help solving this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I can successfully compute the 200 day moving average for one ticker using a SQL query, I'm trying now to create a VIEW.  I am stuck the following query seems logical but there is a SQL error
"#1054 - Unknown column 'equity.TickerID' in 'where clause'"

```
SELECT  AVG(Close) AS MA200 FROM equity
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Close 
    FROM equity_pricehistory  
    WHERE TickerID = equity.TickerID 
    ORDER BY Timestamp 
    DESC LIMIT 0,200
) as Y
```

Comment: I believe views don't support subqueries. I may be wrong, however.

Comment: The subquery has its own scope.

Comment: Adam, I am interested to know if what I am trying to achieve is at all possible in SQL.  I am trying to avoid writing as many C++ utilities as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. This will do the trick.

```
SELECT equity.id, AVG( equity_pricehistory.close ) AS MA200
FROM equity
INNER JOIN equity_pricehistory ON equity_pricehistory.TickerID = equity.id
GROUP BY equity_pricehistory.TickerID
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0 , 200
```

One thing I would point out is that you could totally ignore the whole `equity` table if you already know all the TickerIDs you want are in `equity_pricehistory`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to return a table with the MA200 for all 10,000+ tickers.  It looks like this query will not do that.

Comment: Can you please give us your schema? I'm not sure I understand which columns are where

Comment: equity_pricehistory the columns are TickerID, close,timestamp.  Table equity, tickerID <data>.  In english, equity contains a list of equity tickers.  and price history is the big table containing all the daily quotes for all tickers.  I want to generate a query that gets a table of MA200 for all tickers.